# What version of "ngx-bootstrap" should I install for "Angular 17"?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Here is the version

[image]

I was trying to download `ngx-bootstarp` but didn't found any compatible version. I have google it but there was no information about it. I saw the list in the official site of Angular bootstrap, there was no update about the version 17.0.0

Comment: In the meantime, you can configure version overrides for `ngx-bootstrap`, as I did [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/package.json#L91-L98) for ng-mocks

Answer (score 3):

If you used ngx-bootstrap so its not support yet angular 17.
You can check below image also, angular all supported version available there
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a version supporting Angular v17 now. Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) and scroll down to the Compatibility section

Answer (score 1):

There is no version that officially supports v17 yet. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/6618) if you want track the support.

You can still install it with `--legacy-peer-deps`, there shouldn't be any issue.